# Faceted heatmap plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I want to construct a faceted heatmap plot in R. I ave attached my sample code for that. Everything is working fine but the only issue I am facing is that I don't want the locations to be arranged in an alphabetic sequence. Please have a look at the code and figure. I need the location sequence to be **purulia,bankura,jhargram** rather than **bankura, jhargram, purulia**

```
 df <- data.frame(chr=c("SWAT","SWAT","VIC","VIC","MOD16A2","MOD16A2"),
                 year=c("2001_K","2002_K","2001_K","2002_K","2001_K","2002_K"),                 
                 purulia=c(-12,0.56,-0.35,0.49,0.11,0.23),
                 bankura=c(-43,-0.56,0.35,0.74,-0.11,0.89),
                 jhargram=c(0.13,-0.12,-0.41,0.16,-0.69,0.42))
df.l <- reshape(df, [enter image description here][1]
                varying = c("purulia", "bankura", "jhargram"),
                idvar="chr",
                v.names = "NSE",
                timevar = "Locations",
                times=c("purulia", "bankura", "jhargram"),
                new.row.names=c(1:(3*nrow(df))),
                direction = "long")
library(ggplot2)
df.l$year <- factor(df.l$year)
ggplot(df.l, aes(Locations, year)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = NSE)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red") + facet_wrap(~chr)+ 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the levels of the factor in the wanted order using e.g.

```
df.l$Locations <- factor(df.l$Locations, levels = c("purulia", "bankura", "jhargram"))
```